# Alias to create aliases

Tags: git, alias

How can I write a git alias that will let me create more aliases?

For example:

```
git alias st status
```

Should create a new alias for `git status` under `st`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each alias is simply an entry in the `alias` section of a git config file.  For instance, if `zog` were an alias, it would be `alias.zog`

To update a git config file, you can use `git config` with one of the options to choose which configuration file to update.  The most appropriate such options are `--global` (affecting your personal config file that applies to all repositories) and `--local` (affecting the current repository only, i.e., an alias that only works in one repo).  The default is `--local` but `--global` usually makes more sense for aliases.

So let's consider a trivial example, to make `git zog` mean the same thing as `git log`:

```
$ git config --global alias.zog log
$ git zog --oneline
a17003a change f1
9af3861 initial
```

Now let's change it from meaning `log` to meaning `frog`:

```
$ git config --global alias.zog frog
$ git zog
Expansion of alias 'zog' failed; 'frog' is not a git command
```

Last, we'll remove it, since this is just for illustration and it's time to clean up:

```
$ git config --global --unset alias.zog
$ git zog
git: 'zog' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

Did you mean this?
    log
```

You say you want an alias that creates more aliases.  That means we want the alias `alias` to run `git config`.  This would almost work:

```
git config --global alias.alias 'config --global alias.'
```

except for one very big problem: with this alias in place, running `git alias st status` results in the equivalent of the command:

```
git config --global alias. st status
```

when we want one that has `alias.st` as the first argument.  Also, we'd run into issues with the remaining arguments if there were more than one: `git config` would get them split up inappropriately.

Thus, we need to resort to invoking the shell.  There are many ways to code the remainder.  They are hard to type in as shell commands; it's easier to edit the config file and put them in manually (`git config --global --edit` will do this, or you can just invoke your editor directly).

Here's an example from the git authors (I added some backslash-newline bits to make it fit better on StackOverflow; note that you *can* write the alias this way in your various config files):

```
[alias]
    alias = "!sh -c '[ $# = 2 ] && \
        git config --global alias.\"$1\" \"$2\" && exit 0 || \
    echo \"usage: git alias <new alias> <original command>\" >&2 && exit 1' -"
```

To make this one work I had to add another `-` right at the end (not shown above); I'm not really sure why, probably some FreeBSD `sh` variance.

Here's my version of the same thing, using shell functions to handle arguments.  If you supply more than two arguments, all the extras are combined:

```
[alias]
    alias = "!f() { a=\"$1\"; shift; \
        git config --global alias.\"$a\" \"$*\"; }; f"
```

So now:

```
$ git alias st status --short
$ GIT_TRACE=1 git st
trace: exec: 'git-st'
trace: run_command: 'git-st'
trace: alias expansion: st => 'status' '--short'
trace: built-in: git 'status' '--short'
```

(or just look at the config file, with editor or `git config --get`).

These—both versions—are still slightly defective as they can try to re-alias an existing alias.  It might be better to see if `alias."$1"` is already in the config file, and if so, complain (or require an argument like `--overwrite` or a different alias like `realias` or some such).  Feel free to experiment with what git does with multiple entries for, e.g., `alias.foo`, and see the documentation for [`git config`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html) for how `git config` deals with multiple entries (they *are* allowed, under various circumstances).

As a general rule, once your git alias starts getting hairy like this, it's probably better to just write a shell script (or shell function) for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script that is named `git-createalias` and it will work as you would expect, such as `git createalias`.  Make it a bash command or use your favorite scripting language.  Use it to create a new alias for you right from the command line.

For instance, create a bash (or other programming language) and name it `git-newalias` and have it accept whatever arguments.  Have it write the required format to `.gitconfig` and then the next git command will read the file and you have the solution you desire.  As @torek explains more fully, you can do so, but I still recommend just writing a git-command to do so as a script (shell) program, and using it as you want.

They are different, but consider that you can implement the functionality with a script (sure, use bash, or your favorite language) by name.  Git itself is a collection of independent files that look like you are doing commands, such as git commit, being git-commit, in actuality.  See the `ls /usr/lib/git-core` for example on a common linux distribution.  [See this post from 2012](http://cfmumbojumbo.com/cf/index.cfm/coding/create-your-own-custom-git-command/) that also details this.  An example of this directly is the git-stash shell script in that folder.

When I do this for things that only my account needs, I place them in `~/bin` and `chmod +x <command>`.

Comment: Shell aliases and git aliases are slightly different beasts, I believe it was asking about the latter (which could be implemented by the first, most likely).

Comment: @Leigh You are likely correct, but I would recommend not doing so for sanity.  As an exercise, it is as torek shows a worthwhile lesson.  But it is the harder way to go about doing so.